# Why does requestScope cause the error 12501?

Tags: android, google-signin

I create my `GoogleSignInOptions` object like so:

```
gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(Games.SCOPE_GAMES_LITE)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

and I get error 12501...
when I do

```
        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

everything works fine (except that I then lack the GAMES_LITE scope later on...)

Why does the requestScope cause a crash? What can I do?